# Use Submit Button with PhantomJS

Tags: jquery, button, phantomjs, submit

Very new to PhantomJS. I filled in a username and password using document.querySelector() and want to now submit the information. I have cookies enabled; my issue is finding the button to submit. The button of interest is:

```
<button class="signbtn loginbtn" type="submit">Sign In</button>
```

This is inside a form:

```
<form name="loginf" method="post" action="/login">...</form>
```

I have tried each of the following without success:

```
document.querySelector(".loginf").submit();

document.querySelector(".loginf").click();

document.querySelector("loginf").submit();

document.querySelector("loginf").click();
```

and

```
var form = document.getElementByClass("loginf");

form.submit();

form.click();
```

For the credentials, I successfully used:

```
          document.querySelector("input[name='email']").value = "EMAIL";
          document.querySelector("input[name='password']").value = "PASS";
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the form doesn't have a class of "loginf", that's the value of the name attribute. You could try using an attribute selector:

```
document.querySelector("[name=loginf]").submit();
```

Comment: Thank you, this was perfect. 

I may make another Q for this, but if you have a moment, this is my next problem.

After I evaluated a page (put it credentials, and logged in) I want to go to another page. 

I know I can put another "page.open" outside of the page.evaluate but inside the first page.open, but cookies seem to be lost after this. Anyway to keep the cookies?

Comment: An alternative is to click on the link:

    <a href="/questions"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>Questions</a>

But I am not sure how to get that from just that.

Comment: Well for the first method, one thing you could do is grab the cookies inside the `page.evaluate` call and store it to a global that can access them later on in that first `page.open`. Try using `page.cookies` and `page.addCookie` to add back the pertinent cookies

Comment: For the alternative you proposed, you could use the same line of thinking as for getting the element with name loginf. `document.querySelector("a[href=/questions]").click();`

Comment: I appreciate the help a lot so far. `document.querySelector("a[href=/questions]").click();` 

produces:

`SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12: An invalid or illegal string was specified.

  undefined:8 in querySelector
  :8
  :15`

Then,

`document.querySelector("a[href='/questions']");`

runs fine. 

However,

`document.querySelector("a[href='/questions']").click();`

Produces:

`TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector("a[href='/questions']").click')

  undefined:10
  :15`

Is it not selecting the link?

Comment: This is the selector if at all helpful:

`#s-t-menu > li:nth-child(3) > a`

Comment: Hmm, looks like it isn't finding it with just the href attribute. That's a bit odd, but fine. You could do it using a different selector, and yes, something to give me the heirarchy of the html on the page is exactly what I needed. Try that as the query selector then: `document.querySelector("#s-t-menu > li:nth-child(3) > a").click();`.

Comment: Did not work either! I also tried:

`$("#s-t-menu > li:nth-child(3) > a").click();` 

with 

`page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function(){`

after the `page.open` and before the `page.evaluate` but that also did not work!

Comment: Hmm, I'd recommend moving this to a chat since the comment thread is getting somewhat long. But what I'd try doing is first logging the element to see if it's being selected at all. Rather than calling `click()` on it right away, store it in a variable first and inspect that, see if it is coming up as undefined or an empty array

Comment: I do not have enough Reputation to create a chat- but am happy to do one if you can set it up.